# New line character is not rendering properly by jquery

Tags: jquery

i am show text on a images one after one. so each line has `<BR>` tag but when text is showing on image using jquery then BR is not properly translated rather empty space is coming at the top of the page.
here is my script

```
<div id="HeaderMessage" class="HeaderMsg1">
<span class="HeaderMsg">A LIFETIME WARRANTY FOR EVERY PART WE REMANUFACTURE.<br/>We reengineer the faults out of parts so they won't fail again. Guaranteed.</span>
<span class="HeaderMsg">PROFIT FROM ENGINEERING EXPERTISE.<br/>We offer you reliable parts, low prices and easy access to automotive knowledge.</span>
<span class="HeaderMsg">JOIN US FOR A CAREER THAT CAN TAKE YOU FURTHER, FASTER. <br/>Reengineer your future with a world leader in the remanufacture of electronic automotive parts.</span>
<span class="HeaderMsg">THE SENSIBLE CHOICE IS THE GREENER CHOICE TOO.<br/>Our parts save precious raw materials, reduce automotive waste and require less CO2 to produce. </span>
</div>

$('.HeaderMsg1 span:gt(0)').hide();
    setInterval(function () {
    $('.HeaderMsg1 :first-child').fadeOut()
    .next('span').fadeIn()
    .end().appendTo('.HeaderMsg1');
 }, 5000);
```

i am not being able to show new line with text when showing text on the image on after one.
please help me. thanks

Comment: If the idea is that you need spacing after each "HeaderMsg", you should add some CSS to make that class appear as a block and give it some dimensions and padding. It's not obvious what the issue is though based on your description, or what it is you have/do not have

Comment: Your `<br/>`s may not be working properly as you may (depending on your doctype) require a after the r i.e. `<br />`. Alternatively do what @SpaceBison said and use CSS which is a far cleaner method.

Comment: @Chris - there shouldn't be an issue with <br/> without the space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an issue with your selectors.

Firstly, `.HeaderMsg1 :first-child` (which really is `.HeaderMsg1 *:first-child`, which isn't the same as `.HeaderMsg1:first-child`) translates to:

Find `.HeaderMsg1`, after which get any element that resides under it, which also is a `first-child` from its parent (can be any parent). That will result in all `span`'s and `br` elements, which results in all the `br`'s being appended on the first interval.

I believe what you really were after was `'.HeaderMsg1 span:first-child'` (or something similar), which should give you the effect you are after.

example:
http://jsfiddle.net/49kvB/

Comment: thanks ur code works but honestly i just do not understand the way u describe the problem. it would be better if u plzz describe the problem in more detail....what was the problem in my code. thanks u rock.

Comment: @Thomas Your selector isn't selecting the items you intend it to select. Remove the interval, do a `console.log("$('.HeaderMsg1 :first-child')");` to see what it actually selects, then do the appendTo and see what the result is. It is just a problem with the elements you are selecting

Comment: i think $('.HeaderMsg1 :first-child') select first span in parent div? when <BR/> comes in scene then problem occur before it was working fine. can u discuss why problem occur when <BR/> comes in text with in span text.

Comment: @Thomas `$('.HeaderMsg1 :first-child')` does select the first child in parent div, which happens to be a `span`. But it **also** selects the first child element of each of the elements under .HeaderMsg1. The first element in all `span`s is a `br` and as such those are also selected.